# How to store words from the sentence

Tags: c++

I have the following C++ code that calculates the total number of words and stores the the value in count variable.
So, the question is how can I store those particular words from a sentence in a variable so I can later use them to match the words in the sentence if I pass a word to match with.

Thanks for the help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <new>
#include <cctype>

int wordsInString(const char* );

int main()
{
    wordsInString("My name is Donnie");
    return 0;
}

int wordsInString(const char* s)
{
    int count = 0;
    int len = strlen(s);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        while(i<len && (s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == '\t' || s[i] == '\n'))
        {
            i++;
        }
        if(i<len)
        {
            count++;
            while(i<len && (s[i] != ' ' && s[i] != '\t' && s[i] != '\n'))
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "The total count: " << count << std::endl;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: `std::map` is what you are looking for

Comment: The normal "input" operator `>>` separates on space. So you can [read a line](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), put it into an [input string stream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and use [input stream iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) to put it into a vector (using the iterator [overload of the vector constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)).

Comment: Or of you want to map a "word" to a counter for the word (i.e. make a histogram of word occurrences) then perhaps a [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) with the word as the key and the counter as the data. Use e.g. `while (input_stream >> word)` to read all words one by one.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can you explain that in a simple language. i am a beginner

Comment: @Federico I cannot use any other header file apart from the ones that are mentioned. It' a assignment by a psycho professor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question author shows a code that works and counts the number of words. Perfectly fine. The question is, how to store the words now. And not only count.

In a comment at the end, the author says that they are allowed to use the mentioned headers only. Unfortunately, this will invalidate all other answers.

The reference to the headers is not only a restriction, but also a proposal solution.

The OP is obviously taking a C++ class and is building up know-how at the moment. But, of course still far away from mastering one of the most complex programming languages.

But if we start to ignore the requirements, then the problem can always be solved with a one-liner. No complex recursive stuff and nonsense needed.

---

So, first I will also ignore the requirements and show the one-liner approaches.

Later, I will show what the professor wants to see.

---

All this relies on the fact that we have container in C++ and iterators to iterate over the elements in those containers. You will find this everywhere. E.g. something with `begin()` and `end()`. And there are many iterators for many different purposes.

For example, if you have a string (which is a container for characters), then you can simple use iterators to iterate over all characters in the string.

But there is, since many many years, a special iterator to iterate over patterns, like for example words in a string. This is a dedicated iterator that is specifically designed for this purpose.

And because it is specifically designed for this use case and it is simple to use and very flexible, it should be used.

We are talking about the `std::sregex:token_iterator`. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator) for a description. You can simply define a pattern in simple regex language, like for a word, and then iterate over all words. Brutally simple.

OK, now that we know that we have a specific and dedicated iterator, especially designed for our purpose, we can use existing functions for iterators, to get our needed result.

First, the count. There is a function called `std::distance`. And as its name says, it calculates the distance between 2 iterators. For example, the distance between the first and the last element is of course equal to the count of elements in any container.

And, as with any iterator, also the `std::sregex_token_iterator` has constructors. Reading [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator/regex_token_iterator), we can see “begin” iterator will be initialized with the container and a regex. The “end” iterator is the default constructor, without any argument. So, you can simply write `{}` to get the end iterator.

With that know-how, we can write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Some alias name to save typing word and get a more readable text
using Words = std::vector<std::string>;
using WordIter = std::sregex_token_iterator;

// A regex to specify a pattern for words consisting of alpha and digit characters
const std::regex re{ R"(\w+)" };

// Test string with some example data
const std::string test{ " My name is Donnie " };
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // One-liner to get the count
    unsigned int count = std::distance(WordIter(test.begin(), test.end(), re), {});
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    std::cout << "\nWe found '" << count<< "' words\n\n";
}
```

That is ultra-simple, has low complexity and is easy to understand.

I appreciate that regexs have something of an overhead, but I don't think that matters here.

---

Next: Storing the words.

If we want to store the words, we would typically use a dynamic container, like a `std::vector`.

And, very nice, the `std::vector` has a constructor, which takes a pair of iterators and then copies all elements. See [constructor number 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

So, everything pointed to by the iterators will be put into the vector. And, additionally, after adding the words to the `std::vector` we have also the “count” of words, because the vector knows how many words are in it.

See the next one-liner:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>


// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Some alias name to save typing word and get a more readable text
using Words = std::vector<std::string>;
using WordIter = std::sregex_token_iterator;

// A regex to specify a pattern for words consisting of alpha and digit characters
const std::regex re{ R"(\w+)" };

// Test string with some example data
const std::string test{ " My name is Donnie " };
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // One-liner to store all words in a vector and get its count
    // Define a container that will contain all words using the range constructor of the vector
    
    Words words(WordIter(test.begin(), test.end(), re), {});

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Output part: Now we have all words and their count. Show result to user
    std::cout << "\nWe found '" << words.size() << "' words\n\nAnd these are:\n\n";
    for (const std::string& w : words) std::cout << w << '\n';
}
```

Again, an ultra-simple and efficient solution.

By just using the correct container and iterator, we get a compact and very good readable and understandable solution.

---

But now, back to reality. The OP starts to learn the language. All copy and paste of the above advanced stuff will be rejected by the Prof.

So, we need to follow their requirements.

They only want to see functions from:

- iostream  --> Only std::cout
- cstring --> Only C style strings (char *) and C-style string functions
- new --> Handwritten dynamic memory management. No `std::vector`
- cctype -->We may use `std::ispace` to search for spaces.

Especially difficult for newbies is dynamic memory management. But this shall be taught here.

First info: A C-string consists of all the characters and a trailing 0 to terminate the string. This means, if we need to allocate dynamic memory for a string, we need to get “number of characters + 1” bytes.

So, if we have a string “ABC”, then it has 3 bytes. If we want to copy that to dynamically allocated memory, then we need to write: `char* text = new char[3+1];`. This needs to be remembered.

Then, if we want to store more than one string, then we need a 2 dimensional array. One dimension for the characters that form the words and the second dimension for the number of words.

So, a `char**`

There are two possibilities to dynamically allocate such an array. First, we count all words and then allocate an array with this count: `char** wordList = new char*[count];`.

Or, we follow the full dynamic approach, we define some default capacity for such an array, like for example 1 element. Then, if the array is full, we double the capacity (so, getting 1,2,4,8,16,…) and allocate a new array. Something like:

```
if (count >= capacityOfArray) {
    // Not enough capacity. Get more. Double capacity
            capacityOfArray = capacityOfArray * 2;

            // Create new array with bigger capacity
            char** temp = new char* [capacityOfArray] {};
```

And then copy all data from the old array to the new array. We must not forget to release the memory of the old array after we copied all the elements.

Anyway. All dynamically allocated memory must be released!

With that, we get the following code, which fulfils all requirements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <new>
#include <cctype>

int wordsInString(const char * s, char **& wordList)
{
    int count = 0;
    int beginOfWord = 0;
    int endOfWord = 0;

    // Create an array that can hold a number of string. InitialCapacity will be 1
    int capacityOfArray = 1;
    // Create the array. Allocate memory, Initialize with nullptr
    wordList = new char *[capacityOfArray] {};

    // How many characters do we have in the string.
    int len = strlen(s);

    // Check each character in the string
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        // Search the beginning of a word, so the first non white space character
        while (i < len && std::isspace(s[i]))
        {
            i++;
        }
        // We remember the start position of the word
        beginOfWord = i;
        if (i < len)
        {
            // Look for the end of the word, either a white space or end of string
            while (i < len && !std::isspace(s[i]))
            {
                i++;
            }
            // Here we have the end position of the word
            endOfWord = i;

            // What is the length of the word that we just found 
            int wordLength = endOfWord - beginOfWord;
            if (wordLength) {

                // Allocate new space for the newWord variable
                char* newWord = new char[wordLength + 1]{ '\0' };

                // Copy the current evaluated word into our variable
#pragma warning(suppress : 4996)
                strncpy(newWord, &s[beginOfWord], wordLength);

                // Check, if we have enough capacity in our array for this new word
                if (count >= capacityOfArray) {
                    // NOt enough capacity. Get more. Double capacity
                    capacityOfArray = capacityOfArray * 2;

                    // Create new array with bigger capacity
                    char** temp = new char* [capacityOfArray] {};

                    // Copy all pointers from old array to new array
                    for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) {
                        temp[k] = wordList[k];
                    }
                    // Release old memory for words 
                    delete[] wordList;

                    // And assign new array to wordlist
                    wordList = temp;
                }
                // Store the latest word in our wordlist
                wordList[count] = newWord;

                // Now, we have one word more
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}


int main()
{
    // This array will hold all words
    char** wordList = nullptr;
    int count = 0;

    // Get all words in string and their count
    count = wordsInString(" My name is Donnie ", wordList);

    // Show result on the screen
    std::cout << "\nThe number of words is: " << count << "\n\n";

    // Now show all extracted words on the screen
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
       std::cout << wordList[i] << '\n';

    // Release all dynamically allocated memory
    for (int k = 0; k < count; ++k)
        // First delete word by word
        delete[] wordList[k];

    // Delete word list
    delete[] wordList;

    return 0;
}
```

Please note: Such a code is OK for academic purposes. But in C++, we would never use pointers for owned memory or C-Style strings and arrays.

Comment: How can I thank you, sir? Thank you for taking the time

Comment: This looks like a good answer, but was less than diplomatic than I think it could have been. Words matter! A good way to hash out technical disagreement is to put (amenable) criticism to other authors in comments under their posts - sometimes this produces the change that the critique author is seeking.

Comment: Notes on Markdown: block code only needs three backticks, and `inline code` only needs single backticks. It makes material easier to edit when authors can use the minimum symbols to get the formatting they need.

Answer (score 1):

I can offer another way to solve this problem - using the algorithm **Depth first search**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
const int maximumSize=40;
string wordsInString="My name is Donnie";
vector<string> words;
string temporary;
vector<int> visitedWords(maximumSize, 0);
template<class Type>
void showContent(Type input)
{
    for(int i=0; i<input.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout<<input[i]<<", ";
    }
    return;
}
void dfsWords(int current, int previous)
{
    if(visitedWords[current]==1)
    {
        return;
    }
    visitedWords[current]=1;
    if(isspace(wordsInString[current])==false)
    {
        temporary.push_back(wordsInString[current]);
    }
    else
    {
        words.push_back(temporary);
        temporary.clear();
    }
    if(current==(wordsInString.size()-1))
    {
        words.push_back(temporary);
        temporary.clear();
    }
    for(int next=current; next<wordsInString.size(); ++next)
    {
        dfsWords(next, current);
    }
    return;
}
void solve()
{
    dfsWords(0, -1);
    cout<<"wordsInString <- ";
    showContent(wordsInString);
    cout<<endl<<"words <- ";
    showContent(words);
    return;
}
int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
wordsInString <- M, y,  , n, a, m, e,  , i, s,  , D, o, n, n, i, e, 
words <- My, name, is, Donnie,
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstood the problem in my initial comments, but if you just want to count the number of space-delimited "words" in a string, then I recommend using an [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) for the string, then use a loop extracting the space-delimited "words" one by one using the normal input operator `>>` into a dummy string variable, and increase a counter in the loop.

Perhaps something like this:

```
unsigned wordsInString(std::string const& string)
{
    // A stream we can read words from
    std::istringstream stream(string);

    // The word counter
    unsigned word_counter;

    // A dummy string, the contents of the string will never be used
    std::string dummy;

    // While we can read words from the stream, increase counter
    for (word_counter = 0; stream >> dummy; ++word_counter)
    {
        // Empty
    }

    // Return the counter
    return word_counter;
}
```

This works because:

- The result of the `>>` stream extract operator is the stream itself, and when converted to a boolean value it will be false when we reach the end of the stream, which breaks the loop; And
- The stream extraction operator separates on white-space (space, newline, tab, etc.); And
- For each successful extraction of a word from the stream, we will increase the counter, so the loop counts the "words" in the stream.

Comment: Uh, why don't you use a `while` loop instead?

Comment: @justANewbie There's no need to. The `for` loop does the work just the same, and is more compact (though perhaps not in the extra verbose way I've written it) and just as easy to understand.